# Где удобно хранить sql запросы Dapper

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, dapper

Приложение на asp core. Использую Dapper для запроса данных из бд (только select'ы). Запросы довольно большие, много join'ов case'ов и т.д. Поэтому думал хранить запросы в отдельных файлах .sql, чтобы легко их отлаживать, ну и не засорять код. Нигде не замечал такую практику. Есть ли проблемы в таком подходе? Или может есть другие решения?

Comment: Имхо, это нормальная практика. Можно ещё эти файлы в ресурсы поместить.

Comment: Или в БД. И в коде останется один-единственный запрос - на получение текста нужного запроса...